# Why am I getting 500 errors when making a query to the LinkedIn Profile API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to debug an issue that appeared for us on December 9th. We use the LinkedIn Profile API to login/register users on our platform and also optionally allow them to sync data from their LinkedIn profiles to their profiles on our platform. Since the 9th however, login and registration are both broken. We hadn't changed code related to this before the errors started coming.

Now, instead of receiving basic user profile data when trying to log someone in to our platform, we get errors from the LinkedIn API. These are coming from a Node.js server that was using the now deprecated `request` package, but has since been moved to `axios` and is still producing the error, albeit more verbose which is helpful. The error received from `axios` is as follows:

```json
{
  "message": "write EPROTO 140075354449792:error:140920E3:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:parse tlsext:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1157:\n",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: write EPROTO 140075354449792:error:140920E3:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:parse tlsext:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1157:\n\n    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:868:14)",
  "config": {
    "transitional": {
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "User-Agent": "axios/0.24.0"
    },
    "method": "get",
    "url": "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token=access-token-goes-here&projection=(id,firstName,lastName,maidenName,headline,summary,educations,skills,industryName,positions,vanityName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))"
  },
  "code": "EPROTO",
  "status": null
}
```

I've read several times that this is an SSL error, and that it may be related to using HTTPS for an unsecured endpoint (definitely not the case) or there could be a mismatch in the TLS version used, which I don't believe is the issue either.

However, I also decided to take the URL and manually query it with a REST client, and instead got this error:

```json
{
  "serviceErrorCode": 0,
  "message": "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 147",
  "status": 500
}
```

This indicates to me that there is a bug in the LinkedIn API somewhere. I've also verified that a similar error occurs when querying `api.linkedin.com` from [Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.linkedin.com) and [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/help/) cannot connect to this domain either.

Have I got something wrong here? Is the LinkedIn API currently broken? Is this a response to log4j mitigations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after looking everywhere, the issue come from nodejs versions.

I tried a lot of things, changing request libraries, upgrading nginx and using TLS 1.3 version... etc

But the solution is using node 10+, I was using node 9.8 (I have test with 8.11, 10.24 and 14.18)

Resume :

- 8.11 -> ssl error
- 9.8 -> ssl error
- 10.24 -> OK
- 14.18 -> OK

This is ennoying as changing node version could imply breaking changes...

Comment: We tested this on our end as well, and _luckily_ updating the node version didn't break anything. We were on Node 8, now on 14 and it's working again. Thanks for your debugging effort!